# How to convert string to integer and determine if it's less than Int32.MinValue or greater than Int32.MaxValue?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have the following piece of code which attempts to determine whether a given string is a valid integer. If it's an integer, but not within the valid range of Int32, I need to know specifically whether it's greater than Int32.MaxValue or less than Int32.MinValue.

```
try
{
     return System.Convert.ToInt32(input);
}
catch (OverflowException)
{
     return null;
}
catch (FormatException)
{
     return null;
}
```

Convert.ToInt32 will throw the OverflowException if it's not in the range of acceptable values, but it throws the same exception for both greater than and less than. Is there a way to determine which one it is aside from parsing out the text of the exception?

Comment: not really a good fix, but convert it to Int64 then compare it?

Comment: Convert to long instead of int?

Comment: @dtb: Same problem if the value overflows long though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you're using .NET 4, you could use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) - parse to that, and then compare the result with the `BigInteger` representations of `int.MaxValue` and `int.MinValue`.

However, I would urge you to use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268243.aspx) instead of catching an exception and using that for flow control.

Comment: I thought about that, but doesn't that leave me with the same problem? Since (when using TryParse) the output will be 0 in the case of the number being out of range, I seem to have the same problem of determining whether it's greater than or less than.

Comment: @The Matt: How can `BigInteger` be out of range? The whole point of it is that it provides arbitrarily large integers... in other words, if `BigInteger.TryParse` returns `false`, you know the input was fundamentally invalid. Otherwise, compare the output with `(BigInteger) int.MaxValue` and `(BigInteger) int.MinValue` to check for the range.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. You meant use both of those suggestions in combination. Got it.

Comment: @The Matt: yes, definitely :) That's why the link for TryParse is to `BigInteger.TryParse`.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert it to `Int64` (i.e. `long`) instead, and then do the comparison yourself. That will also eliminate an exception as control flow situation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way to know if the input that threw an OverflowException (or gave a false if you used TryParse) is more than Int32.MaxValue or less than Int32.MinValue: a number less than Int32.MinValue will be a negative one, so its string representation will begin with a '-' !

Answer (score 0):

The idea is:

```
bool isWrong = false;
bool isLarge = false;
if (!Int32.TryParse(rawValue, out int32Holder))
{
      if (!Int64.TryParse(rawValue, out int64Holder))
      {
           isWrong = true;
      }
      else
      {
           isLarge = true;
      }
}
```